# Private container registry for argocd applications with their own namespace

Tags: argocd

I am trying to use argocd to deploy an application which has its own namespace. I am also using my own selfhosted container registry.

I created a secret to use for pulling from my registry.

```bash
kubectl -n argocd create secret docker-registry <my-registry-name> --docker-server=myregistry.example.com --docker-username=<myuser> --docker-password=<mypass>
```

Then I add the secret to argocd image updater config.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-image-updater-config
data:
  registries.conf: |
    registries:
    - name: My Registry
      prefix: myregistry.example.com
      api_url: https://myregistry.example.com
      credentials: pullsecret:argocd/<my-registry-name>
      default: true
```

I create an application:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: registry.example.com/ns/myapp:v0.1.4
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: git@git.example.com:<my-user>/<my-repo>.git
    targetRevision: main
    path: .
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
      allowEmpty: false
    syncOptions:
      - Validate=true
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - PrunePropagationsPolicy=foreground
      - PruneLast=true
```

My deployment file looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myregistry.example.com/ns/myapp:v0.1.4
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

When I am running sync and refresh in argocd I get pullBackOff because I am unauthorized, But even if I specify :lastest on the image it will still figure out the latest version.

I tested if argocd image updater would work with the container registry, and it worked fine with the same configuration as used in the cluser.

I thought that the problem might be that the image is pulling inside another namespace than `argocd` when it is deploying an app that has the namespace `myapp` so I tried adding

```yaml
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <my-registry-name>
```

to the deployment.yaml and it turns out to work fine. But then I have to define the imagePullSecrets in every single deployment I am making. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong here. Because all the tutorials are showing that I don't need to define the container registry secret other places than in argocd namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a pull secret specified in every namespace.